# In VBA OutLook, how do I string together Namespace property specifiers? I'm trying to filter inbox by subject line for both unread and read emails.

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to parse through my inbox by subject line for both unread and read emails.
However, when I parse through subject line only, the filter returns only read emails.

```
'Filters inbox by subject line (only returns READ emails)
strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " LIKE '%M4 Vitals Grade%'"

'Returns Entire Inbox (READ AND UNREAD emails)
strFilter2 = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:read" & Chr(34) & "=True"

'Does not work...
strFilter3 = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " LIKE '%M4 Vitals Grade%' WHERE " & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:read" & Chr(34) & " = true"

Set filteredItems = objFolder.Items.Restrict(strFilter)
```

Please let me know if you need more information! Thank you

Comment: I specified a sub-folder within my outlook inbox. This seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following one:

```
strFilter =" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " LIKE '%M4 Vitals Grade%' AND [UnRead] = True"
```

Comment: [strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " LIKE '%M4 Vitals Grade%' AND [UnRead] = True"]



Thank you Eugene, however this returned a Run-Time error Cannot parse condition.